# How to write custom select all for antd table to filter tags in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, antd

```
const TagsList = [...new Set(modifiedData.flatMap(item => item.tags))].filter(tag => typeof tag === 'string' && tag.trim() !== '');
const tagFilters = [
    {
        text: 'Any',
        value: 'any', 
    },
    ...TagsList.map(tag => ({
        text: tag,
        value: tag,
    })),
    {
        text: 'No Tags',
        value: '', 
    },
];
const allTags = TagsList.map(tag => tag);
```

I am trying to have a custom select all button called 'any' where when the component renders it should be selected by default and all the other tags must be selected. When I unclick and click 'any' again I am not able to select all other tags including no tags as well. Given below is my tags column implementation:-

```
{
        title: 'Tags',
        dataIndex: 'tags',
        key: 'tags',
        filters: tagFilters,
        defaultFilteredValue: ['any', ...allTags, ''],
        onFilter: (value, record) => {
            if (value === 'any') {
                return true;
            } else {
                return (record.tags.includes(value));
            }
        },
        filterSearch: true,
    },
```